# Search type links in Yahoo - how to implement similar behaviour

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html, css

When you open the [yahoo main page](http://uk.yahoo.com) at the top there is a search section that contains links like: Web, Images, Video, More

When clicking on the link the chosen section is activated and the text of the search button is being changed. The only part of the page that is updated is the search part at the top and **the other parts of the website remain unaffected.**

My question is how is this implemented? And more importantly **how similar behaviour could be
   implemented in .net using VS 2008?**

Are the links really links or different elements that only mimic the links behaviour?
Does it need to be ajax, or just everything is preloaded and hidden using some css techniques?

Is the same technique used in the news section on the same page when changing tabs: News, Sport, Entertainment, Video?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually done with CSS and Javascript:

```
<ul id='menu'>
  <li><a href="#web_search" class='active'>Web</a></li>
  <li><a href="#image_search">Image</a></li>
  <li><a href="#video_search">Video</a></li>
  <li><a href="#local_search">Local</a></li>
</ul>

<div id='web_search' class='search'></div>
<div id='image_search' class='search' style='display: none;'></div>
<div id='video_search' class='search' style='display: none;'></div>
<div id='local_search' class='search' style='display: none;'></div>
```

Then Javascript (example uses jQuery, can be done many ways...):

```
$('a','#menu').click(function() {
    $('div.search').hide();
    $('a.active', '#menu').removeClass('active');
    $($(this).addClass('active').attr('href')).show();
    $(this).blur();
    return false;
});
```

[And this is an example of it in action](http://jsbin.com/amube). The styling and such would all be CSS.

Comment: Thank you Paolo, that is very helpful. I wish I could upvote your answer more then once

Answer (score 2):

After doing a quick inspection of the search field using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), it appears that clicking on each of search type links (Web, Images, etc) simply modifies the DOM. This includes adding fields, removing fields, toggling class names, etc. I wouldn't be surprised if hidden fields are also being manipulated.

Behavior like this is accomplished using JavaScript. Specifically (and at a very high-level), there are event handlers attached to the links each of which modify the DOM in their own way.

It can definitely be implemented using Visual Studio 2008 as it's really (and likely) nothing more than CSS, JavaScript, and HTML. .NET really wouldn't come into play until you're ready to take the specified query and begin running it against your data store.

[Paolo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978591/search-type-links-in-yahoo-how-to-implement-similar-behaviour/978634#978634) gives a really good, straight-forward example of how that behavior can be emulated.

Comment: Thank you Tom, that makes sense. There is no need for ajax as there is no data provided by the user that would require server level interaction

Answer (score 1):

Those links have onlclick JavaScript handlers attached to them. When you click on them different tab becomes visible and current tab gets hidden. All tabs are preloaded but only the first one is visible initially.

Take a look at [Tabs control](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Tabs/Tabs.aspx) from ASP.NET AJAX control toolkit. You can customize tabs so that they look like links.